# Better and simpler solution for API authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an API and I'm stuck at the authentication part. I will try to explain what I have and what I'm trying to accomplish:

- First, the API is closed to the public, it will only be used on the admin's back-end and for 3rd party devices in the company.
- I have a model called Member that is being used with Devise for authentication
- I'm also using STI to distinguish between 3 levels of users (using CanCan for roles)

What I thought:

- I tried the Token authentication by Rails, it worked but I was afraid of expose the token in each Ajax request, I don't know if I was right.
- I also tried to use a '/token' route to post my credentials and get a token, but I was facing the same problem in a more complicated approach. [The link with the tutorial](http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/)
- I don't wanna use OAuth because it's unnecessary for that kind of application.

Is it secure to use this token authentication with ajax requests or is there a more secure way to prevent people accessing my API?

Comment: anyone? I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Token authentication needs to be done over a secure connection.
If for example you are using Heroku, it is possible to use
their credentials to gain a HTTPS url. With this the contents
will be encrypted and so exposing the token through JSON
over the API will be acceptable.